Trying to edit an .hdf5 file but when recording video it doesn't seem to want to copy
This is a project done in google colab. I'm given a .hdf5 file with robot trajectory demonstrations. The assignment is to film new trajectories using architectures we've learned about in class. I've done that, it's the copying the new trajectory to a new .hdf5 file that seems to be an issue
def segment_data(f, filename, num_demos, testing):
    keys = list(f["data"].keys())  # get all demonstration ids

    for i in range(1, num_demos):  # iterate over all demonstrations
        subfile = filename + ".hdf5"
        if os.path.exists(subfile):
            os.remove(subfile)
        f_new = h5py.File(subfile, "w")
        grp = f_new.create_group("data")
        grp.attrs.create("env_args", f["data"].attrs["env_args"])  # copy over the environment args
        grp.attrs.create("total", f["data"].attrs["total"])  # copy over the "total" attribute

        # copy over each of the next demonstrations to the new group
        f.copy("data/{}".format(keys[i]), grp, name=keys[i])

        # edit 'obs' data if it exists
        if 'obs' in grp[keys[i]]:
            # Modify 'robot_eef_pos' data here
            grp[keys[i]]['obs']['robot0_eef_pos'][:] = [[1.1, 2.1, 3.1] for _ in range(len(grp[keys[i]]['obs']['robot0_eef_pos']))]
            grp[keys[i]]['obs']['robot0_gripper_qpos'][:] = [[0.0, 0.0] for _ in range(len(grp[keys[i]]['obs']['robot0_gripper_qpos']))]

        

        f_new.close()

f is a pointer pointing to the file that contains the robot trajectories, filename is the file I want to save it to, num_demos is the number of demonstrations in f (yes I know this code will overwrite every bit of data except the last demonstration. I plan to fix that later) testing is well, the new demonstrations I want to test. But currently I'm trying to make it so that 'obs' basically stays constant for every end effector position and gripper position. When I print out. When I have a pointer pointing to the new file and asking it what the values are, it correctly says the constants I put in, but when I use the function to play the video, the trajectory is identical used as a demonstration

I haven't checked your code. You said when you read the new file it prints the new constants you added. If so, the problem is not in your h5py code. Check the function used to play the video.

I looked a little closer and noticed you create the same new file INSIDE the loop on range(1, num_demos). So, only the changes on the the last loop will be saved. Also, these range values will start on key[1] and skip the 1st key: key[0]. Is that your intent?

Yes it was. I thought yesterday to look at the function used to create code but apparently it works by updating action not state, which is what my code updates. So the actions being fed are identical and I don't know how to change it.
